# i want to increment or decrement date on click , eg if click next button 5 times i must get date of after 5 days

Tags: android

i want to increment or decrement date on click , eg if click next button 5 times i must get date of after 5 days,if i click on previous button 3 times it must show me date prior to 3 days

public class PanchangView extends AbstractActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
        private CardView today,previous,next;
        private TextView currentd;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_panchang_view);

            today=(CardView) findViewById(R.id.card_current);
            previous=(CardView) findViewById(R.id.card_previous);
            next=(CardView) findViewById(R.id.card_next);
            currentd=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtcurrent);


            Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
            final String[] Month=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.months);
            int dd=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int mm=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int yy=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            currentd.setText(new StringBuilder().append(dd).append(" ").append("-").append(Month[mm]).append("-")
                    .append(yy));

            previous.setOnClickListener(this);
            next.setOnClickListener(this);

        }


       public void onClick(View v){


           int id=v.getId();
           switch (id){

               case R.id.card_previous:{final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                   final String[] MONTHS = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.months);
                   c.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);  // number of days to add
                   int dd= c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                   int mm = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                   int yy = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                   currentd.setText(new StringBuilder()
                           .append(dd).append(" ").append("-").append(MONTHS[mm]).append("-")
                           .append(yy));}break;

               case R.id.card_next:{final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                   final String[] MONTHS = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.months);


                   c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);// number of days to add
                   int dd= c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                   int mm = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                   int yy = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                   currentd.setText(new StringBuilder()
                           .append(dd).append(" ").append("-").append(MONTHS[mm]).append("-")
                           .append(yy));}break;

           }

      }
```

Comment: the only issue on your current code is that, you are creating new instance of calendar, everytime you click on button, kindly use obj 'cal' which you declare onCreate() method